# Making my first discord bot, unable to add anything besides basic commands

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm using discord.js as well as javascript to code. I'm just trying to work out this test bot I have made and despite all the step-by-step guides that I have pretty much followed to a T, I am only able to get the bot to work with basic "ping pong" like commands. Every time I try to add anything more or less, the bot completely stops working.

Here is an example of the code I have so far. It's a little 'gaggy' some friends and I, as I said, are just trying to work out how to make the test bot first. Maybe it's just completely going over my head and I'm just not doing it the correct way. Either way, some assistance would be helpful. Thanks.

```
        /*
  A ping pong bot, whenever you send "ping", it replies "pong".
*/

// Import the discord.js module
const Discord = require('discord.js');

// Create an instance of a Discord client
// This is sometimes called 'bot', but 'client' is prefered
const client = new Discord.Client();


const token = 'MY_BOT_TOKEN';


client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('I am ready!');
});

// Create an event listener for messages
client.on('message', message => {
  // If the message is "ping"
  if (message.content === 'silas!ping') {
    // Send "pong" in the same channel
    message.channel.send('pong');
  }
});

// Log our bot in
client.login(token);
```

What I am also trying to do is add a "SAY" command, this is what I have been using, and once I add it, it completely breaks the bot. As well as adding in a prefix.

```
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.channel.type != 'text' || message.author.bot || !message.startsWith('*'))
    return;

  if (message.content === '*ping') {
    message.channel.send('pong');
  }
});
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.channel.type != 'text' || message.author.bot || !message.startsWith('*'))
    return;

  if (message.content === '*ping') {
    message.channel.send('pong');
  }

  else if (message.content === '*say') {
    message.channel.send(message.content);
  }
});
```

Im not sure if this means anything to get help, but this is the error i recieve when trying to add the following code given to me for help

if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
^

ReferenceError: message is not defined
at Object. (C:\Users\my location files\index.js:23:1)
[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)[39m
[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)[39m
[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)[39m
[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)[39m
[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47[39m

Comment: What do you mean by "completely breaks"? What message are you sending, what's it doing, what do you expect it to do? I posted an answer based on what I think your issue is, but in the future please add more details to help others answer.

Comment: Right sorry. I mean "completely breaks" as in NONE of the codes that had previously worked before any changes don't work either. I apologize for the lack of detail.

Comment: Not really a djs question. Now it's up to you to know programming to create special commands

Comment: So, there are some guides who explain exactly how to handle commands. I posted an answer which might help. But please look into tutorials or into [this](https://discordjs.guide/) guide where you can find a more detailed explanation.

Comment: i actually used that guide to help build the bot however, im having troubles with it. i even started from scratch a few times but i always get stuck after adding the prefix and say commands

Comment: Did you also compared their code with yours? Do you use the current version of Discord.js? I mean, if the second code block is your actual code, then the only thing which is wrong is, that you try two times to do any action with the .on('message') event call. You only need one .on('message) call and not two.

Answer (score 1):

Another, little more advanced, way would be to seperate the prefix and the command.
This allows you to define a prefix without changing all `.startsWith()` conditions.

With `Array.split()` you can seperate each following word if they have whitespaces between each other.

This would end up like this:

```js
let prefix = "*";

// Prevents any unnecessary condition checks if the message does not contain the prefix
if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

const args = message.content.toLowerCase().split(' ');

let command = args[0];
command = command.slice(prefix.length);

if(command === "say"){
   // do whatevery you want :)
}
```

After it was checked that the message starts with the prefix, you split each word and then take the first one. With slicing the prefix out, you end up with only having the plain command. This allows an even better approach for checking commands since the condition doesn't include the prefix anymore.

Everything after `args[0]` would be additional arguments you can use for any case you want.

Answer (score 0):

you could make a `config.json`.

inside your config.json

```
{
   "TOKEN": "",
   "PREFIX": "",
}
```

and then require on you bot main file and also define the `client.commands` and `client.aliases`

```
const config = require("./config.json");
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
client.aliases = new Discord.Collection();
```

on your message event you wanna add a command handler

```
client.on("message", async(message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (!message.guild) return;
    if (!message.content.startsWith(config.PREFIX)) return;
    if (!message.member) message.member = await message.guild.fetchMember(message);

    const args = message.content.slice(config.PREFIX.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    
    if (cmd.length === 0) return;
    
    let command = client.commands.get(cmd);
    if (!command) command = client.commands.get(client.aliases.get(cmd));
    try {
    if (command) 
        command.run(client, message, args);
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
})
```

after that, add a new folder call `handlers` and inside the `handlers` folder make a new file call `command.js`

```
const { readdirSync } = require("fs");

const ascii = require("ascii-table");

let table = new ascii("Command");
table.setHeading("Command", "Load Status");

module.exports = (client) => {
    readdirSync("./commands/").forEach(dir => {
        const commands = readdirSync(`./commands/${dir}/`).filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"));
    
        for (let file of commands) {
            let pull = require(`../commands/${dir}/${file}`);
    
            if (pull.name) {
                client.commands.set(pull.name, pull);
                table.addRow(file, '✅');
            } else {
                table.addRow(file, `❌  -> missing a help.name, or help.name is not a string.`);
                continue;
            }
    
            if (pull.aliases && Array.isArray(pull.aliases)) pull.aliases.forEach(alias => client.aliases.set(alias, pull.name));
        }
    });

    console.log(table.toString());
}
```

and then require on the bot main file

```
["command"].forEach(handler => {
    require(`./handlers/${handler}`)(client);
});
```

make a new folder call `commands` inside add new folder command category such as `info`
simple ping command

```
module.exports = {
   name: "ping",
   aliases: ["pong"],
   description: "Check Bot Ping",
   usage: "",
   run: async(client, message, args) => {
       messsage.channel.send("PONG")
   },
};
```

hope this guide is helpful :)